# CSS files not working in Chrome preview but show in Dreamweaver Live

Tags: html, css, adobe, dreamweaver

I have an issue where my webpages dont work on Chrome with the CSS not working however the in-app preview on Adobe Dreamweaver shows it all working, does anyone know how i can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post the source code view from dreamweaver, specifically the link tags to your stylesheets. My first guess would be the relative path is not correct.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/uK0g6c7q

Comment: Just for grins try editing your source and remove the leading / from the style paths so: "/styles/style-home.css" become "styles/style-home.css"

Comment: @Adrianopolis That worked cheers bud, its stupid how picky languages can be when it comes to file paths XD

Comment: yes but take care because if you for example were to copy that page and move it up a directory it would break. the forward slashes are best practice. Ideally dreamweaver would have a better development environment. A root needs to be defined. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that Chrome is up to date. You may want to consider reinstalling Chrome. Next, make sure you have a DOCTYPE declaration and that it is for HTML 5. Finally, make sure your CSS is not malformed and, if you are using references to external sheets, that the address is correct, or even consider having it right in the document.
If all else fails, try it in IE or Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have HTML and CSS in a single file, and that may fix the issue.  All you need to do is place a `<style type="text/css"></style>` tag somewhere in your HTML file, and fill it with all your CSS code.

It should look something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.class1{
    /*class1 style*/
}
.class2{
    /*class2 style*/
}
#id1{
    /*id1 style*/
}
#id2{
    /*id2 style*/
}
</style>
```